# ¿Es una buena práctica de programación guardar la referencia del objeto dentro del mismo en una variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, rendimiento

Me estoy encontrando que pierdo la referencia al propio objeto cuando hago un callback y he visto por internet que se puede solucionar con esto.

```
var Imagen = function(){
    var __self = this;
    var __posY;
    var __posX;

    this.inicializar = function(){
    }
}
var imgObj = new Imagen();
```

Mi pregunta es, a nivel de memoria consumida esto es rentable? imaginaos que puedo llegar a crear 200 imagenes... si cada una está guardandose a sí misma... o si por el contrario, únicamente se guarda la referencia a memoria a ese objeto y no el objeto en sí mismo, con lo que no habría en ese caso ningun problema a nivel de rendimiento, entiendo...

Muchas Gracias!

Comment: No me termina de quedar clara la pregunta. Realmente la estás respondiendo en tu propia publicación.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es un problema para la memoria, ya que en Javascript **todo objeto se pasa por referencia** (no así los tipos primitivos). Y puesto que necesitas el contexto, de un modo u otro necesitarás guardarlo.

Sobre si es una buena práctica... es algo sujeto a opiniones, ya que existen otras opciones que son prácticamente equivalentes: usar funciones flecha o aplicar `miFuncion.bind(this)`